# Python creating dataframes with loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I would like to create numbered data frames from a list of names, as follows:

```
tickers = [‘IBM US Equity’, ‘AAPL US Equity’]
for num, ticker in enumerate(tickers, start=1):
      df[num] = df.loc[ticker]
      print(df[num])
```

df is another pandas dataframe with the tickers as it’s index. So writing out the following does indeed give me the desired result:

```
df1 = df.loc[‘IBM US Equity’]
print(df1)
```

However, when trying to use the loop I’m getting an error message:
“Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1”

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary for a variable number of variables:

```
tickers = ['IBM US Equity', 'AAPL US Equity']

df_dict = {}

for num, ticker in enumerate(tickers, start=1):
      df_dict[num] = df.loc[ticker]
```

Then access elements via `df_dict[1]`, etc.

An alternative way to formulate your logic is to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
df_dict = {num: df.loc[ticker] for num, ticker in enumerate(tickers, 1)}
```

The *reason* your code errors is `pandas` is trying to add a dataframe to a series: the left hand side of `df[num] = df.loc[ticker]` is a series, while the right hand side is a dataframe. This is not possible and, fairly descriptively, `pandas` complains about an incorrect number of items.